# React select generic type for key with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following component that wraps a Material UI select:

```
  return (
    <Box display="flex" justifyContent={justifyContent}>
      <SortWrapper>
        <InputLabel htmlFor={id} shrink={true} >
          Sort by
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          data-bdd={id}
          id={id}
          defaultValue={defaultSortOrder}
          onChange={handleChangeSort}
        >
          {options.map((f: any) => (
            <MenuItem key={f.sortableKey} value={f.sortableKey}>
              {f.displayName}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </SortWrapper>
    </Box>
  )
```

and than I use it like so inside the UI:

```
...
              <SelectInput
                defaultSortOrder={defaultSortOrder}
                handleChangeSortOrder={handleChangeSortOrder}
                style={selectInputStyle}
                id="repairs-search-sort"
                options={sortableFields}
              />
...
```

and sortableFields is like so:

```
sortableFields: SortableField[]
```

the key and value are too tight to `SortableField[]`

```
export default class SortableField {
  public displayName: string = ''
  public sortableKey: string = ''
}
```

is there a way to make `key` and `value` values more generic?

Like `<MenuItem key={ket} value={value}>` regardless of the type we are consuming in the UI?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple techniques you can use, which I've seen in various third-party libraries:

1. Define `labelKey` and `valueKey` props.  This will let you define which properties to search for.

```
interface MyInterface1 {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

interface MyInterface2 {
  key: {
    id: string,
    description: string
  };
}

<SelectInput<MyInterface1> labelKey="id" valueKey="name"/>

<SelectInput<MyInterface2> labelKey="key.id" valueKey="key.description"/>
```

2. Expose a callback to return the label and values.  Sometimes you need to grab data outside of the `options` array, or perform some formatting (Dates, Times, Composite labels).

```
interface MyInterface1 {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
}

function buildLabel(option: MyInterface1): string {
  return `${option.firstName} ${option.lastName}`;
}

<SelectInput<MyInterface1> labelCallback="buildLabel" valueKey="id"/>
```